# Python 3 can't find 'gi' module

Tags: drivers, python, python3, gtk3, redshift

This issue began when I was trying to run `redshift-gtk`. I installed the program manually and it runs fine via just `redshift`, but I want it to run with the indicator. I always get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/redshift-gtk", line 26, in <module>
from redshift_gtk.statusicon import run
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redshift_gtk/statusicon.py", line 30, in <module>
import gi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'
```

I do think this is more of a general problem rather than redshift-specific. I already have the necessary pre-requisites installed:

```
python3-gi is already the newest version (3.36.0-1)
python3-gi-cairo is already the newest version (3.36.0-1).
gir1.2-gtk-3.0 is already the newest version (3.24.20-0ubuntu1)
```

I've tried executing `locate python3-gi` and here's the result:

```
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128/usr/share/doc/python3-gi
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128/usr/share/doc/python3-gi-cairo
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128/usr/share/doc/python3-gi/changelog.Debian.gz
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128/usr/share/doc/python3-gi/copyright
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128/usr/share/doc/python3-gi-cairo/copyright
/usr/share/doc/python3-gi
/usr/share/doc/python3-gi-cairo
/usr/share/doc/python3-gi/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/python3-gi/copyright
/usr/share/doc/python3-gi-cairo/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/python3-gi-cairo/copyright
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-gi-cairo.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-gi-cairo.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-gi.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-gi.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-gi.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-gi.prerm
```

So I have no idea why I am having a "No module named 'gi'" error. I also have python-gobject installed:

```
python-gobject is already the newest version (3.34.0+2.28.6-14ubuntu1)
```

Here's my current linux version:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you should know that RedShift is packaged in [all Ubuntu versions](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=redshift).

To remove locally installed stuff use:

```
sudo python3.8 -m pip uninstall redshift-gtk
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/redshift
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/redshift-gtk
```

So you can simply install RedShift from repository with:

```
sudo apt-get install redshift redshift-gtk
```